# Restore deleted amplify backend with cognito user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

recently I tried to add an app to use the same backend than other amplify app. Somehow it did  a push and had overwritten my old backend. I also lost the user Pool and all the users. Is there any way that I can restore the app or at least my users? I don't want to ask them to sign up again